# i use boost 1.3.0 in visual studio 6.0

Tags: c++

the souce code like this:

```
#include <boost/pool/singleton_pool.hpp>
struct pool_tag{ };
typedef singleton_pool<pool_tag,sizeof(int)> sml;

void main()
{
    int *m=(int *)sml::malloc();
}
```

the error is :

```
error C2248: 'object_creator' : cannot access private struct declared in class 
   'boost::details::pool::singleton_default<
       struct boost::singleton_pool<struct pool_tag,4,
       struct boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete,
       class boost::details::pool::win32_mutex,32>::pool_type>'
```

i do not know how to fix it ?can somebody help me ?

Comment: OT, but why are you still using Visual Studio 6.0? You would be far better off with a more recent version. There is the Express edition of VS which is free.

Answer (score 1):

From Boost mailing list thread [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/5714), try upgrading to at least Boost 1.3.1.

If you can upgrade to VC7.1 as well then it will definitely work.

Another mailing list thread [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2002/07/1237.php) mentions that Boost Developers where trying to determine the error in 2002 but doesn't say anything further.